# How can I set a logging level and match the line in python?

Tags: python, linux, unix, logging

I created a log file in python using

`logging.basicConfig(filename = DIR6, format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s :: %(message)s', level = logging.DEBUG)`

and DIR6 is the path and the name of log file.

I am logging many things in many different positions.

I want to know how can I turn some log conditions off and on instead of deleting all the time when I don't need it.

for example, lets say I have

```
logging.info("Inside of dir_checker if loop")
logging.info("Found: " + dir_path)
```

at first it prints out both logs. Maybe in next run, I want to log only first condition. I need to turn 2nd one off..

How can I write this?

---

2nd question is. How can I put all logs in line?

I am using above logging.
It prints out

```
2015-03-23 10:28:44,843 INFO :: Inside of main if loop for no more files to   work on
2015-03-23 10:28:44,843 INFO :: Stats directory is removed from the Processing directory
2015-03-23 10:28:44,844 DEBUG :: Sent Email message: All finished
2015-03-23 10:28:44,844 INFO :: Main method is finished
2015-03-23 10:28:44,844 INFO :: Setting stop to True to stop the progress
2015-03-23 10:28:44,844 DEBUG :: stop set to True
```

which looks little ugly becasue :: is all over the places.. and log starts in different places..

how can I do something like

```
2015-03-23 10:28:44,844 DEBUG :: Sent Email message: All finished
2015-03-23 10:28:44,844 INFO  :: Main method is finished 
2015-03-23 10:28:44,844 INFO  :: Setting stop to True to stop the progress
2015-03-23 10:28:44,844 DEBUG :: stop set to True
```

Comment: 1. Why are you putting in logs you don't want? 2. Tabs?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am just using it as above as an example. Because of the testing servers and production servers.. we need to turn some logs off depends on the case.. that's why I want to know if there is a way to do it other than just deleting the log from python.

Comment: Also for the second part.. `logging.basicConfig(filename = DIR6, format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s :: %(message)s', level = logging.DEBUG)` this is what I am using and it generates INFO and DEBUG by it self.. where can I put tab? because it is generating by it self, I can't put any tabs

Comment: Why not use the logging levels (or define your own, if the current levels are insufficient) and just have different handling of the levels in the different environments? And `'...(levelname)s\t:: %(message)s'`?

Comment: Can you give me an example coding for it?

Comment: I suggest you start with e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am sorry..  i read.. but kinda don't get how I can control logging by doing what is on that website